# Jolt spec to remove element from array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

For my input json, I need to write a Jolt spec that can remove the **externalId** field from the list of **externalIds** in order to avoid repeating this element in the list.

Input:

```json
{
  "id": "id_1",
  "targetId": "targetId42",
  "externalId": "1extid",
  "attributes": {
    "uniqueInfo": {
      "externalIds": [
        "3extid",
        "2extid",
        "4extid",
        "1extid",
        "5extid"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```json
{
  "id": "id_1",
  "targetId": "targetId42",
  "externalId": "1extid",
  "attributes": {
    "uniqueInfo": {
      "externalIds": [
        "3extid",
        "2extid",
        "4extid",
        "5extid"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone please help with this query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consecutively use **`"$":"@(0)"`** tecnique in order to remove the array which is generated due to coincident values (**`1extid`**) of **`externalId`** within **shift** transformation specs such that

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "externalId": "attributes.uniqueInfo.externalIds.@(0)", //exchange key-value pair
      "@(0,externalId)": "externalId", //multiplexing value to keep for later steps
      "attributes": {
        "uniqueInfo": {
          "externalIds": {
            "*": {
              "@(4,externalId)": "&4.&3.&2.@(0)" //exchange key-value pairs
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "attributes": {
        "uniqueInfo": {
          "externalIds": {
            "*": {
              "$": "&4.&3.&2.@(0)"//exchange key-value pairs again
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "attributes": {
        "uniqueInfo": {
          "externalIds": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&4.&3.&2[&]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Barbaros. Accepted the answer.